# SQL DB2: Declare Temporary Table Add Column

Tags: db2, alter, temporary

I have declared and temporary table successfully.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.MY_TEMP_TABLE
LIKE MYTABLES.AN_EXISTING_TABLE
INCLUDING IDENTITY
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
WITH REPLACE;
```

I then use the following to merge two tables and output this into my temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO SESSION.MY_TEMP_TABLE
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM MYTABLES.TABLE_A) as a
     LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM MYTABLES.TABLE_B) as b
ON a.KEY=b.KEY;
```

Now this above all works.

ISSUE: I now want to merge on two new variables from a further table (MYTABLES.TABLE_C), however it will not let me because I declared the temporary table with a certain number of columns and I am trying to add further columns. I did a google and it seems ALTER TABLE will not work with DECLARED TEMPORARY tables, any help please?

Comment: Drop your session table and recreate it with ALL the necessary required columns, then re-populate it.  You may want to consider the `NOT LOGGED` option for faster performance.  The session table will also be dropped if you disconnect your session.   Consider using the `WITH REPLACE` option for the DGTT to make recreating the table less hassle.

Comment: I should have said I want to drop the table after the session is ended, this is why I have used the SESSION. prefix.

When you say create it will all columns required, there are over 300 columns which could change, I do not want to write 300 lines out when I could use the LIKE option.

Comment: @mao - Is there a possibility to use the LIKE option and to define a few extra columns?

Comment: Think differently. Create an *additional* session table based on your existing session table, plus whatever other tables you need. Much faster if `NOT LOGGED`. Example. `declare global temporary table session.m1 like emp including identity on commit preserve rows with replace not logged;
declare global temporary table session.m2 like org including identity on commit preserve rows with replace not logged;
declare global temporary table session.m3 as (select * from session.m1, session.m2) with data with replace not logged;`

Comment: You can also use `definition only` and do the merge later.

Comment: This helped! I ended up doing what you suggested (defining two tables then defining a third based on those two). I also added the WITH NO DATA option as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Session tables (DGTT) need to be declared with all the required columns , as you cannot use `alter table` to add additional columns to a session table.

A way around this limitation is to use session tables in a different manner, specifically to create a new session table on demand with whatever additional columns you need (possibly also including the data from other tables).  This can be very fast when you use the `NOT LOGGED` option. It also works well if your session table uses `DISTRIBUTE BY HASH` on environments that support that feature.

Here is an example that shows 3 session tables, the third of which has all columns from the first two tables:

```
declare global temporary table session.m1 like emp including identity on commit preserve rows with replace not logged;

declare global temporary table session.m2 like org including identity on commit preserve rows with replace not logged;

declare global temporary table session.m3 as (select * from session.m1, session.m2) with data with replace not logged;
```

If you do not want to populate the session table at time of declaration you can use `DEFINITION ONLY` instead of `WITH DATA` (or use `WITH NO DATA`)  and populate the table later via insert or merge.